# Searching keywords using facebook graph API in Python

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, sentiment-analysis

I recently started working on sentiment analysis for which I need data from Facebook/Instagram post/comment/replies. I plan to search a keyword or tag and would get data from the results. I looked up facebook graph api and some blogs and I found code of 2016 which did exactly that but it isn't working.

```
import urllib3
import facebook
import requests  

token= # mytoken
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version = 3.1)
events = graph.request('/search?q=Poetry&type=event&limit=10000')
```

This code finds information on events for any search term say “Poetry” and limiting those events number to 10000

but when I run it I get the following error:

[image]

Tell me if it possible and what I should do to fix it.

Comment: No, that is not possible any more. Facebook has removed most types you could search for, I think all that is left is search for pages, and some stuff in the Marketing API. A search for public posts containing specific keywords, does not exist any more.

Comment: thanks bro! also do you if LinkedIn has this functionality?